# Unable to open socket, connection timed out

Tags: php, sockets, source-engine

Trying to sent packages from my webhost to a game server, using this code. However it always results in `Unable to open socket: Connection timed out (110)` ad I can't figure out why it times out. When I try this on my localhost, it works perfectly but when on webhost, it just times out. I've tried to set the timeout to something else but it didn't help.

```
define("SERVERDATA_EXECCOMMAND",2);
define("SERVERDATA_AUTH",3);

class RCon {
    var $Password;
    var $Host;
    var $Port = 27015;
    var $_Sock = null;
    var $_Id = 0;

    function RCon ($Host,$Port,$Password) {
        $this->Password = $Password;
        $this->Host = $Host;
        $this->Port = $Port;
        $this->_Sock = @fsockopen($this->Host,$this->Port, $errno, $errstr, 30) or
                die("Unable to open socket: $errstr ($errno)\n");
        $this->_Set_Timeout($this->_Sock,2,500);

        }

    function Auth () {
        $PackID = $this->_Write(SERVERDATA_AUTH,$this->Password);

        // Real response (id: -1 = failure)
        $ret = $this->_PacketRead();
        if ($ret[1]['id'] == -1) {
            die("Authentication Failure\n");
        }
    }

    function _Set_Timeout(&$res,$s,$m=0) {
        if (version_compare(phpversion(),'4.3.0','<')) {
            return socket_set_timeout($res,$s,$m);
        }
        return stream_set_timeout($res,$s,$m);
    }

    function _Write($cmd, $s1='', $s2='') {
        // Get and increment the packet id
        $id = ++$this->_Id;

        // Put our packet together
        $data = pack("VV",$id,$cmd).$s1.chr(0).$s2.chr(0);

        // Prefix the packet size
        $data = pack("V",strlen($data)).$data;

        // Send packet
        fwrite($this->_Sock,$data,strlen($data));

        // In case we want it later we'll return the packet id
        return $id;
    }

    function _PacketRead() {
        //Declare the return array
        $retarray = array();
        //Fetch the packet size
        while ($size = @fread($this->_Sock,4)) {
            $size = unpack('V1Size',$size);
            //Work around valve breaking the protocol
            if ($size["Size"] > 4096) {
                //pad with 8 nulls
                $packet = "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00".fread($this->_Sock,4096);
            } else {
                //Read the packet back
                $packet = fread($this->_Sock,$size["Size"]);
            }
            array_push($retarray,unpack("V1ID/V1Response/a*S1/a*S2",$packet));
        }
        return $retarray;
    }

    function Read() {
        $Packets = $this->_PacketRead();

        foreach($Packets as $pack) {
            if (isset($ret[$pack['ID']])) {
                $ret[$pack['ID']]['S1'] .= $pack['S1'];
                $ret[$pack['ID']]['S2'] .= $pack['S1'];
            } else {
                $ret[$pack['ID']] = array(
                    'Response' => $pack['Response'],
                    'S1' => $pack['S1'],
                    'S2' => $pack['S2'],
                );
            }
        }
        return $ret;
    }

    function sendCommand($Command) {
        $Command = '"'.trim(str_replace(' ','" "', $Command)).'"';
        $this->_Write(SERVERDATA_EXECCOMMAND,$Command,'');
    }

    function rconCommand($Command) {
        $this->sendcommand($Command);

        $ret = $this->Read();

        //ATM: Source servers don't return the request id, but if they fix this the code below should read as
        // return $ret[$this->_Id]['S1'];
        return $ret[0]['S1'];
    }
}
```

If I specify udp connection in fsockopen it does not timeout, however if I try tcp, it times out. Most likely caused by the host, but I have no idea where to go from this.

https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_RCON_Protocol
https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Server_queries

Comment: Is the gameserver on the same server as the webserver? Have you checked the firewall?

Comment: Different server. I have no clue about the webhosts firewall, but most hosts allows such connections (from what I know). And as stated, works on localhost for me (a different machine as well).

Comment: Then you should make sure that you actually _know_ if the port is open on that particular server with your webserver.

Comment: Not quite sure what port you're talking about. I checked both TCP 27015 on localhost and the webhost, both are closed.

Comment: You have to check port 27015 outbound on your webserver. You say it works on your computer, but not on the server. So it is obviously not a code issue. The webserver simply cannot establish a connection to your gameserver.